# Decrypting byte array from Java in C++ using RSA with java generated keys

Tags: java, c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I need to decrypt file in C++. What I have is byte array and pair of keys generated in Java using KeyPairGenerator from java.security;

Java Code:

```
public void generateKeys() {
    try {
        final KeyPairGenerator pairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithmName);
        pairGenerator.initialize(1024); //1024 - keysize
        final KeyPair keyPair = pairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        savePublicKeyIntoFile(keyPair);
        savePrivateKeyIntoFile(keyPair);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Class EncryptionTool.generateKeys() ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String encrypt() throws Exception {

    // Encrypt the string using the public key
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(publicKeyFilepath));
    final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();

    // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithmName);
    // encrypt the plain text using the public key
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    byte[] cipherText = null;
    **cipherText = cipher.doFinal( loadPassword() );**

    return changeByteArrayToString(cipherText);
}
```

I have generated keys saved in files and this cipherText array in C++.
What should I use to decrypt this ?

Comment: SO is not a code conversion service, ntokarsk.